# prevent new branches being created in a git bare repo

Tags: git, git-branch, githooks

We have our main bare repo which has a hook that is supposed to push a specific branch to another remote bare repo.  The the other repo is only supposed to have the one branch. The post-receive hook checks to see if the current commit is on the specific branch (using git rev-parse specific_branch_name) and if so does a:

```
 git push ssh://git@remote/path/to/repo
```

Now we did something silly and pushed a new branch (which was on the same commit as specific branch).  The hook pushed this and a new branch on the other remote was created.

Now obviously we need to delete that branch from the other remote.  However I want to know how to make the other remote refuse to create new branches (it should have only the one specific branch and no others).  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [`update` hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#update):

> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which
>   happens when a git push is done on a local repository. Just before updating
>   the ref on the remote repository, the update hook is invoked. Its exit status
>   determines the success or failure of the ref update.
>
> The hook executes once for each ref to be updated, and takes three parameters:
>
> - the name of the ref being updated,
> - the old object name stored in the ref,
> - and the new objectname to be stored in the ref.
>
> A zero exit from the update hook allows the ref to be updated. Exiting with a
>   non-zero status prevents git-receive-pack from updating that ref.

Simply check whether the branchname is correct and refuse the update
otherwise.